# Blocking websites per user

Tags: networking, firewall, website-blocker

I need to block specified websites, but each user should get his own rules, for example:

1. John cannot access Facebook
2. Alex can access Facebook, but cannot access Youtube
3. The boss can access everything.

There are more than three users, each user has a fixed internal IP that can be used for identification. I do not have access to the computers/phones/etc of the users, everything has to be done on the network level.

Any existing products that can do this or should I go straight to building my own solution using bind and views?

Comment: What OS should that run on? Any price limit? Doesn't your router feature such a filter list (per IP)?

Comment: My organization used WebSense and Group Policy in our Windows domain, until the agency was mandated to use a citywide solution. I don't know what the citywide solution is, but it still involves setting rights via group policy within our organization.